# Ubuntu Touch support of Pebble (Time)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there a possibility to use Pebble (Time) with Ubuntu Touch?

There is a lib ([libpebble](https://github.com/pebble/libpebble)) to use the Pebble Watch with a computer (and someone has [make an app](https://github.com/smokku/pebble) for SailfishOS which use this lib), is but there a possibility to use it with Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a video by Alan Pope, showing an Ubuntu phone connected to the Pebble Time watch.

> Pebble / Ubuntu Phone integration
>
> **Published on Nov 20, 2015**
>
> A quick teaser showing an incoming call notification from Ubuntu phone to the Pebble Time watch. It's early days for this work by a Canonical Developer Michael Zanetti, to get Ubuntu Phone and Pebble watch talking to each-other. Apologies for the potato quality video.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hgvKC2HWp8

Comment: I have improved this answer, to save it from being downvoted. No upvote from me; Let other users decide whether this answer is still relevant or not.

Answer (score 1):

The project is now called RockWork and is working very good with my Pebble

- https://launchpad.net/rockwork

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it is not possible as far as I know.
maybe in the future? but for now, ubuntu touch needs to pickup polularity for developers to be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called upebble that is bringing a community supported app for pebble paired to ubuntu phone

- https://launchpad.net/upebble
- http://wayneward.co.uk/ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-touch-and-pebble-watch-upebble/

  Soon to be released on the openstore... wait :)

Answer (score 0):

i have my pebble steel connected to ubuntu HDE5 phone 
basically you install the open store app 
from here https://open.uappexplorer.com/
instuctions on page, to be honest its pretty straight forward
then just install rockwork (the new name for the apps) inside that - pair the phone and you get notifications and health etc, plus can control music on phone which is handy.
Also inside the openstore is loads of other handy apps

Im going to add a new blog post with a updated version to install rockwork for pebble on the ubuntu touch devices.